# Password encoder bad credentials Spring Boot 2.7.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, authorization

Pretty new with JWT, login and so on.. so I've been watching some tutorials and this is the closest I've come, but i get bad credentials error.

So I'm struggeling with an Bad Credentials-error when i try to do a login, and it seems like the password has two types of encoding when I'm trying to debugg and see what's going on.

Here it is where it breaks in auth-controller,

[image]

The images below shows the encoded password i get from UserDetails and how the encoded password throws an error and doesn't look the same at DauAuthenticationProvider.

[image]

The "userNotFoundEncodedPassword" doesn't match the original encoded password

[image]

My configuration for security,

```
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableMethodSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public JWTFilter jwtFilter() {
        return new JWTFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/test/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authProvider());


        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

Userdetailsservice-impl

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.getByUserName(username).get();
        return UserDTO.build(user);
    }
}
```

My auth-controller

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {

    private AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private UserService userService;
    private RoleService roleService;
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword());
            System.out.println(authenticationToken.getPrincipal());
            System.out.println(authenticationToken.getCredentials());
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManagerBuilder.getObject().authenticate(authenticationToken);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            String jwt = jwtProvider.createToken(authentication);
            System.out.println(jwt);
            JwtDTO jwtDTO = new JwtDTO(jwt);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jwtDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you need more information, I'm a bit lost about this and can't think straight for now, that's why I need help.
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: why are you not using the built in JWTFilter that exists in spring security?

Comment: Hey @Toerktumlare! Thank you for your answer, the only documentation i can find about that is the OAuth 2.0 with JWT at Spring, is that what you mean? And if so.. I'll find it pretty difficult to understand, seems like there's not much documentation/tutorials that can explain and go through the process. As you can tell I'm pretty fresh. But I'll have it a go.

Comment: Writing custom security is bad practice. If you have a hard time understanding it i suggest you read the ”architecture” chapter first. Then implement jwt correct and if you run into problems you ask here